# Cursor did not close

Tags: android, database, cursor

That is something weird !
When i run the following activity i get an error:
"Cursor finalized without prior close()"

But i do not use any Cursor here !!!

public class Categories extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

```
//private AdController myController;
private AdView adView;

private static Context mContext;

TextView tv; Button btn_search;
boolean flag;


// The following are used for the shake detection
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private Sensor mAccelerometer;
private ShakeDetector mShakeDetector;
//DatabaseConnector databaseConnector=null;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //--> If API<11 then hide title bar...
    int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (currentapiVersion < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        flag=false;
    } else //--> only if API >= 11 (honeycomb)
    {
        //--> Action Bar settings
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("ΚΑΤΗΓΟΡΙΕΣ");
        //actionBar.setSubtitle("by NKdevelopment");
        //actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        flag=true;          

        //--> Hack to show overflow menu at Action bar even in devices with hard menu button (!!!)
        getOverflowMenu();
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.gridview);


    //---> Αυτό εδώ το πρόσθεσα λόγο ενός crash report.. τεστάρουμε και ..βλέπουμε...
    //---> Δεν το έχω κάνει upload ακόμα...
    WebViewDatabase webViewDB = WebViewDatabase.getInstance(this);  
    if (webViewDB == null) {  
      View adView = findViewById(R.id.adView);  
      if (adView != null)  
        adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);  
    }
    //---> τέλος ελέγχου crash report..


    //---> Disappear up blue button & botton red search button
    if(flag) {
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.sort_by);
        tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btn_search=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
        btn_search.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    mContext=this;

    //---> GridView testing
    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new CustomGridViewAdapter(this));
    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(this);


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {

    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, final View item, final int index, final long     id)
{
    Intent i= new Intent(this, Love_db.class);
    Bundle extracase = new Bundle();
    switch(index)
    {
    case 0:
        extracase.putString("label", "ΤΗΣ ΑΓΑΠΗΣ");
        extracase.putInt("index", index+1);
        i.putExtras(extracase);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
    case 1:
        extracase.putString("label", "ΑΣΤΕΙΕΣ");
        extracase.putInt("index", index+1);
        i.putExtras(extracase);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
    }
}

public void onClickSearch(View v) { showDialog(0); }


@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater=this.getLayoutInflater();

    switch(id)
    {
    case 0: 
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_dialog, null))
        .setTitle("Αναζήτηση μαντινάδας")
        //.setMessage("Αναζητήστε τη μαντινάδα βάση μιας λέξης-κλειδί !")
        .setPositiveButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            EditText mEdit;
            String searchWord;

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                Dialog f=(Dialog) dialog;
                mEdit= (EditText)f.findViewById(R.id.searchWord);
                searchWord= mEdit.getText().toString();

                System.out.println("searchWord= "+searchWord);

                Intent i= new Intent(mContext, Love_db.class);
                Bundle extracase = new Bundle();
                extracase.putString("label", "ΑΠΟΤΕΛΕΣΜΑΤΑ ΑΝΑΖΗΤΗΣΗΣ");
                extracase.putString("searchWord", searchWord);
                extracase.putInt("index", 99);
                i.putExtras(extracase);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    ).create();

    }
    return null;
}


public void onClickAgapimenes(View v) { 
    Intent ff= new Intent(this, Love_db.class);
    Bundle extracase = new Bundle();
    extracase.putString("label", "ΟΙ ΑΓΑΠΗΜΕΝΕΣ ΜΟΥ");
    extracase.putInt("index", 0);
    ff.putExtras(extracase);
    startActivity(ff);
}

public void onClickKainourgies(View v) { 
    Intent nn= new Intent(this, Love_db.class);
    Bundle extracase = new Bundle();
    extracase.putString("label", "ΚΑΙΝΟΥΡΓΙΕΣ ΜΑΝΤΙΝΑΔΕΣ");
    extracase.putInt("index", 98);
    nn.putExtras(extracase);
    startActivity(nn);
}

private void getOverflowMenu() {

     try {
        ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
        Field menuKeyField =      ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
        if(menuKeyField != null) {
            menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
            menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    AlertDialog.Builder builderExit = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builderExit.setMessage("Επιθυμείτε την έξοδο από την εφαρμογή \"Μαντινάδες\";");
    builderExit.setPositiveButton("Έξοδος", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               finish();
           }
       });
    builderExit.setNegativeButton("Παραμονή", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

           }
       });
    builderExit.create();
    builderExit.show();
}

@Override
protected void onStop()
{
    if (cc!=null){
        cc.close();
    }
        super.onStop();
} // end of onStop method


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
  if (adView != null) {
      adView.removeAllViews();
    adView.destroy();
  }
  /*
  WebViewDatabase webViewDB = WebViewDatabase.getInstance(this);  
  if (webViewDB == null) {  
    View adView = findViewById(R.id.adView);  
    if (adView != null)  
      adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);  
  }
  */
  super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

Where did i find that Cursor ?????

P.S. I noticed that i get the error message only once at the first run...

Comment: At `onItemClick` you start an `activity` (Love_db), maybe the problem is there

Comment: The error appears only when i scroll the GridView. I do not change activity and i do not press any button.

Comment: I noticed that when i remove admob ad then i do not see that error !!